# Uploading files to pre-set Google Drive account using API?

Tags: javascript, file, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API to access and manage files. However, I want want the files to be uploaded into a pre-set account, with which I internally store the OAuth credentials for.

As such, I am currently unsure as to how I can upload files to this account, without having the files pass through my server. Is there a way I can upload files to a Google Drive account directly from the client's computer, without risking the exposure of OAuth credentials or other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood your question as follows.

- You want to make users upload files to Google Drive of the special account.
- You want to put the credentials in the server side.

If my understanding is correct, how about using Web Apps? Web Apps  is run by Google Apps Script as a server. I think that you can achieve your situation by using this. There are following 2 patterns for deploying Web Apps.

#### Pattern 1:

Deploy as "Me" to "Execute the app as:" and "Anyone" to "Who has access to the app:".

- In this pattern, the script of Web Apps is run as owner of account. So the authorization for uploading has already been done, when the Web Apps was deployed. The credentials is in the server side.
- Users are required to use own access token. This access token is used for accessing to Web Apps.
- The script of Web Apps is required to be shared with users.

I think that this pattern provides high security for uploading. But it is done with causing any burden on the users.

#### Pattern 2:

Deploy as "Me" to "Execute the app as:" and "Anyone, even anonymous" to "Who has access to the app:".

- In this pattern, the script of Web Apps is run as owner of account. So the authorization for uploading has already been done, when the Web Apps was deployed. The credentials is in the server side.
- Users can upload files without the access token.
- Also the script of Web Apps is NOT required to be shared with users.

I think that in this pattern, users are NOT required to use the access token. So for example, you can set the password for uploading as the query parameters. And also this pattern can be done without causing any burden on the users.

#### Note :

- If you will use the password for uploading as the query parameters, I recommend the pattern 2.

#### References :

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

This flow supposes that you can use Google Apps Script and deploy Web Apps. And also it supposes that the Web Apps is deployed as Pattern 2. This sample script is for uploading files using the browser. Of course, you can upload files using other language with local PC. Please think of this as a sample.

1. Copy and paste the sample script for GAS.

Please copy and paste the following GAS script to your script editor.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.")
}
```

2. Deploy Web Apps.

Please deploy Web Apps like Pattern 2 as mentioned above. When Web Apps is deployed, the URL can be retrieved. This is the endpoint.

3. Upload files from local PC

You can upload files using the following HTML. Please use this on your local PC. And when you use this, please modify `https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec` to the retrieved URL of Web Apps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sample script for uploading file to Google Drive without authorization</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec" id="form" method="post">
        Upload a file
        <div id="data"></div>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.fileName = file.name;
        fr.onload = function(e) {
            e.target.result
            html = '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="' + e.target.result.replace(/^.*,/, '') + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="mimetype" value="' + e.target.result.match(/^.*(?=;)/)[0] + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' + e.target.fileName + '" >';
            $("#data").empty().append(html);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Reference :

- [Uploading Local Files to Google Drive without Authorization using HTML Form](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/2f16f467c94612dc83920a3158614d95)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide some guidance on how to upload files inside of Google Apps Script? Thanks.

Comment: @think123 Can I ask you about the guidance you think? Can you run Google Apps Script? Can you deploy Web Apps? Because I'm not sure about the information that you have already known from your question and comment. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I read through the stuff you linked, which was very helpful. However, I'm at a loss as to how I can use the Google Apps Script service as a POST endpoint to upload files.

Comment: @think123 Thank you for your reply. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have the client sign into some sort of oauth drive api linked program, you could have the client side machine upload it to their own drive account and have it share with your google account. On your server, it could be checking the file list of the drive for changes, and creating a copy of any new files.

Your server could then host some sort of web page with a list of all the files that it copied. The client machine would be looking at that webpage, and would remove the files on their from the client machine, causing no storage to be used on the client's drive account, and you to have your own copies of the files.